# Why doesn't std::vector use an offset?

Tags: c++, vector

Simple question really. When adding to or removing from the front of a vector, why do you need to shift all the elements to accommodate this change? Using an offset instead to modify the index given when indexing into the vector would solve this problem. Granted this could result in (at most) 2 contiguous blocks of data in memory but this seems like a small price to pay to reduce a linear operation to constant time.

Here's an example to be as clear as possible:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', _, _, _, _, _] offset is 0, 4th through 8th position unused.
push_front('M')
['A', 'B', 'C, _, _, _, _, 'M'] offset is -1
```

and then when indexing

```
operator[](size_t index) {
    return backing_array[(index + offset) % size]
}
```

I get this means there might not be one pure contiguous block of data but moving from 1 to 2 doesn't seem like a huge deal in exchange for constant time push and pop front.

Comment: That's what [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is for.

Comment: vector are not made for removing elements in between. You can do it, but there are better containers (e.g. linked list). Vectors guarantee that the elements are stored in contiguous memory

Comment: One reason is that every-time you'd use `std::vector::operator[]` you'd have to add that offset to the index.

Comment: C++ vector indexing isn't even bounds-checked unless you specifically ask for it with `at`. Why would they make everyone pay for these extra operations on every vector indexing?

Comment: What you describe is a very useful container, which the standard library is lacking. However, it needs to go by a different name, since it breaks the guarantees offered by `std::vector`.

Answer (score 13):

> I get this means there might not be one pure contiguous block of data

No, that's the *end of the story* right there. The whole point of `vector` is that it *is* a "pure contiguous block of data". That's a fundamental requirement of the implementation.

The ability to do this is a core part of `vector`'s entire purpose:

```
T *ptr = &vec[0];
ptr+1;
ptr == &vec[1];
```

Therefore, the interface cannot provide additional requirements that would prevent `vector` from being contiguous.

Answer (score 9):

The whole idea behind vector is for a single contiguous data block: For example you can pass them (well, the address of the first element) to C APIs, you get good cache locality, etc.

The standard provides `deque` for *exactly* the scenario you need: fast push/pop for front/back of the container.